# C#: how to return a list of the names of all properties of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class:

```
 public class foo
{
    public IEnumerable<string> stst_soldToALTKN { get; set; }
    public int sId { get; set; }        
    public string stst_LegalName { get; set; }
    public string stst_TradeName { get; set; }
    public string stst_StreetAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a method I can call that would return a list/ienumerable of the names of each property???

For Example:

```
blah foo1 = new foo();
ienumerable<string> foo1List = GetAllPropertyNames(foo1);
foo1List.ToList();
```

Result: 'stst_soldToALTKN', 'sId', 'stst_LegalName', 'stst_TradeName', 'stst_StreetAddress'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var propNames = foo1.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(pi => pi.Name)
```

Comment: Your probably mean `Name` instead of `MemberName`, no?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes, I got mixed up with `MemberType`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
var propertyNames = foo1.GetType()
                   .GetProperties()
                   .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get a list of the properties and from them, select the name:

```
var foo1 = new foo();
var propertyNames = foo1.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlag.Instance)
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();
```

`propertyNames` will now be a `List<string>`.

BTW, you don't need an instance of `foo` for this to work. You can get its type instead by doing:

```
var propertyNames = typeof(foo)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlag.Instance)
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllPropertyNames(object o)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    yield return propInfo.Name;
}
```